# How to catch server side loopback return callback() function for all or individual responses?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, node-modules, loopback

In Node.js using the LoopBack framework, I want to catch all responses that I have send to the client.

```
 return cb(null, {
             success: true,
             msg: "Customer successfully fatch",
             data: {}
     });
```

I want to convert all response for language conversion after all processing.

Can I use any node module for that or is there any other way to implement it?

Comment: Why not create your own function that forwards the calls after transforming your `msg`?

Comment: I want make a global function just like as Middleware. I had written normal complete code for all apis but before sending it to client, i want to process and update the response then i want to send it back to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Remote Hooks](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Remote-hooks.html#context-object) to hook before/after API calls.

The specific one you are looking at is `afterRemote()`

Example:

```
Car.afterRemote('revEngine', function(context, remoteMethodOutput, next) {
    console.log('Turning off the engine, removing the key.');
    // context.res is your Express Response object.
    next();
});
```